# how i can import a variable (e.g. a word) from a external archive in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm developing a little *text-based RPG* for the *windows CMD*. I'm trying to make a more friendly game-saving system (the actual one is based on level codes, and isn't so user friendly). **How i can take a code from a .txt** or another archive **and use it as variable inside my batch code?**
here's the game-saving method i'm using:
for saving:

```
:save1:
echo ultima partida guardada: P1cWyj (copiar el codigo en el campo de abajo tal como se ve)>C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ProjectText_Data\partida.txt
goto save load
:save2:
echo ultima partida guardada: RxcPy7 (copiar el codigo en el campo de abajo tal como se ve)>C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ProjectText_Data\partida.txt
goto save load
:save3:
echo ultima partida guardada: OeycP5 (copiar el codigo en el campo de abajo tal como se ve)>C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ProjectText_Data\partida.txt
goto save load
:save4:
echo ultima partida guardada: P4gcyK (copiar el codigo en el campo de abajo tal como se ve)>C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ProjectText_Data\partida.txt
goto save load
```

For loading:

```
:5:
cls
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------                              
echo                          #### ####  ####  #### ####  #### 
echo                         #   #    #   # # #  #     #   # # 
echo                         #     ####   #   #  #  ####   #   
echo                         ##    #  #   #    ##   #  #   #   
echo                          #### ##### ###  ##### ##### ###  
echo                                          #   #            
echo                                          ####           
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type C:\Users\%username%\Documents\PrjctTxt_Data\partida.txt
set /p answer=Escriba la clave de 6 digitos de arriba (respetando mayusculas y minusculas):
if %answer%==P1cWyj goto inicio_1
if not %answer%==a goto 5
```

Comment: ignore the ascii art, is the old version of the "menu". the new one is more "clean"

Comment: rather than reinventing the wheel, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63619756/12343998) for a simple script that demonstrates a method of saving / loading user specific values by prefixing them with the $ characters and iterates over those prefixed variables with a `for /F` loop over a `Set $` command.

Comment: @T3RR0R looks good, but how i can implement it? Every screen on the "gme" has his own tag (:1: for example)

Comment: `for /f "usebackq tokens=4" %%a in ("C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ProjectText_Data\partida.txt") do set "correct=%%a"` See `for/?` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the example script has a macro for saving location (label) changes - `Loc`, as well as a `Menu` macro that facilitates navigation to indexed labels. An alternative `Menu` macro for non indexed labels [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051636/unexpected-behaviour-when-retrieving-array-values-at-variable-position-in-batch/64053843#64053843). The `Save` macro is built into the `Loc` macro, and is executed whenever the `Loc`ation macro is expanded. When expanding the `Loc`ation macro, substring modification is used to replace `@` with the Label for the current script location.

The best way for you to learn how to use the macro's would be to build a small script with them, defining any initial variables required where indicated prior to commencing the `script body`.

Additional remarks have been added regarding the usage of macro's to aid in their use.

```bat
@Echo off
@Echo off
:new
rem  *********************  Display any existing character names for continuation or deletion of characters
 If Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_save.bat" (Echo/Your Characters:&Echo/&(For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Dir "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_save.bat" /B')Do For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=_" %%o in ("%%~nG") Do  < Nul Set /P "=[%%o] ")&Echo/)
:character
 Set /P "Name=Name: "
 If Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_%Name%_save.bat" (Echo/[C]ontinue / [D]elete?&For /F "Delims=" %%O in ('Choice /N /C:cd')Do If /I "%%O"=="C" (Goto :playon)Else (Del /P "%TEMP%\%~n0_%Name%_save.bat" & Goto :character))
 If "%Name%"=="" Goto :character
:playon
::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    MACRO DEFINITIONS
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(Set \n=^^^
%= Do Not Modify =%
)
Set Menu=CLS^&Set "Copt="^&For %%n in (1 2) Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
 For %%G in (!OPTS!)Do (%\n%
  Set "opt=@%%~G"%\n%
  Set "opt=!opt:_= !"^&Set "Opt=!Opt:~,-1!"%\n%
  Set "Copt=!Copt!%%~G"%\n%
  Echo/!Opt! [%%~G]%\n%
 )%\n%
 Echo/[E]xit%\n%
 (For /F "Delims=" %%O in ('Choice /N /C !Copt!E')Do If "%%O"=="E" (Endlocal^&Endlocal^&Set "Name="^&Goto :New) Else (CLS^&Goto :@%%O))%\n%
) Else Set OPTS=
rem ***  Inventory Macro. Displays all elements for the given group and their current values.
rem :::  Usage: %INV:@=$varname[%
 Set "INV=Echo/&(For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%i in ('Set @') Do (Set "VN=%%i"&^< Nul Set /P"=[!VN:$=!:!%%i!] "))&Echo/"
rem ***  Autosave macro. Can be incorperated into other macro's
rem :::  Usage: %Save%
 Set SAVE=(For /F "Tokens=1 Delims==" %%i in ('Set $') Do (If not "!%%i!"=="" Echo/Set "%%i=!%%i!"))^>"%TEMP%\%~n0_!name!_save.bat"
rem ***  Location Display Macro with autosave macro included
rem :::  Usage: %Loc:@=LocationLABEL%
 Set "Loc=(Set "$Loc=@"&Title !$Loc:_= !)&%Save%"
rem ***  Loot box Macro to generate random loot from specified range of an indexed array
rem ***  !random! %%4 + Index# will access an index range between the index # and 4 above the index number.
rem :::  Usage: %Loot:@=index#%
 Set "LOOT=(For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%i in (`"Set /A i#=!Random! %%4 + @"`) Do For /F "UsebackQ Delims=" %%v in (`"Set /A v#=!Random! %%3 + 1"`) Do (Set "VN=!$Loot[%%i]:$=!"&Echo/You got %%v !VN!&Set /A "!$Loot[%%i]!+=%%v")) 2> Nul & %SAVE%"
rem ***  the below  macros /I /V and /P are not used in this example. - They are an optional method for defining
rem ***  variables prefixed with $ that automatically saves them for reloading
rem :::  usage: %/I:V=Varname%Input Prompt String:
 Set "/I=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set /P "$V=!$PromptStr:$=!: "&%Save%)Else Set $PromptStr="
rem :::  usage: %/P:V=Varname%VariableValue
 Set "/V=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set "$V=!str!"&%Save%)Else Set str="
rem :::  usage: %/A:V=Varname%=Equation
 Set "/A=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set /A "$V!sum!"&%Save%)Else Set sum="
rem *** Wait prompt Macro
rem :::  usage: %Wait:#=Integer value for time in seconds%Wait Prompt String
 Set "Wait=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Timeout # /Nobreak > Nul & (Pause | Echo/!Output!) 2> Nul )Else Set Output="
rem ***  Array definition macro. Asigns the element names to an indexed Groupname (Array), With each element being assigned an initial 0 value
rem :::  Usage: %DefArray%{ArrayName}{Element names as list}
 Set "DefArray=For %%n in (1 2) Do if %%n==2 ((If "!i#!"=="" (Set "i#=0"))&For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%G in ("!List!") Do (For %%i in (%%~H) Do (Set "$%%~G[!i#!]=$%%i"&Set "$%%i=0"&Set /A "i#+=1"))) Else Set List="
rem ***  Usage: %List/D/V:$V=ListName%"VarA=Value" "VarB=Value" "VarC=Value"
 Set "List/D/V=Set "#$V=0"&Set "$$V="&For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (For %%G in (!$V!)Do (Set "%%~G" > Nul &Set /A "#$V+=1"))Else Set $V="
::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    END MACRO DEFINITIONS

::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    Script specific varaiable Definition
REM *** required to be enabled PRIOR to macro Use, AFTER definition.
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem *** Define Initial script variables here.
rem ::: %DefArray% can be used to intialise array elements with a zero value: %DefArray%{ArrayName}{Element names as list}
rem ::: %List/D/V% can be used to define multiple variables as a list %List/D/V:$V=ListName%"VarA=Value" "$VarB=Value" "VarC=Value"
rem ::: %List/D/V% does not prefix variables with $V by default. Values you wish to save, prefix with $
::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    Script Load / Return to last Location saved with %Loc:@=Label%
rem *** Loads Bat script containing Set "$Var=Value" output of %Save% and %Loc:@=Label% macros.
 IF Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_!name!_save.bat" (
  Call "%TEMP%\%~n0_!name!_save.bat"
  Goto :!$Loc!
 )
:Start
 %Loc:@=Start%
::: -------------------------------------------------------------------||    Script Body
```

Comment: can you explain how it works? (without terminology, i'm new at this)

Comment: The save macro uses a for /f loop to iterate over variables prefixed with the `$` character via the command `Set $`, splitting the output into variable name and value using the for loop options `tokens=1,2 Delims==`. The output of the For /F loop is redirected to a batch save file that can be called to load saved values. Positioning of the load test - `If exist ... Call ...` after Name selection and base variable assignment ensures script flow functions as intended.

Comment: Labels are tracked and saved by expanding  the Loc macro with the current labelname for labels you wish to use as 'Savepoints'